# Case on where clause ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, case

```
SELECT *
FROM (
                SELECT P.PC_ID, PC.PC, P.BLOK_ID, B.BLOK, B.ID_MATERIAL, M.MATERIAL, M.NO_MATERIAL, P.START_DTTM, TO_CHAR(P.START_DTTM,'yyyy-mm-dd') DATE_PERENCANAAN
                FROM UTSG_PERENCANAAN P
                INNER JOIN UTSG_PC PC
                        ON P.PC_ID = PC.ID_PC
                INNER JOIN UTSG_BLOK B
                        ON P.BLOK_ID = B.ID_BLOK
                LEFT JOIN UTSG_MATERIAL M
                        ON B.ID_MATERIAL = M.ID_MATERIAL
                WHERE P.NO_LAMBUNG = '341'
                                AND P.LOKASI_ID = '2'
                                AND P.START_DTTM < TO_DATE('2019-01-09 23:40:52', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
                ORDER BY P.START_DTTM DESC
)
WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN BLOK = 'DD11'
            THEN ROWNUM <= 1
        ELSE
            THEN ROWNUM <= 2
    END
```

I have query like this, on case in where clause always show

> error ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih why? We don't need sample data in order to fix a syntax error.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: While the given answers are syntactical correct, I assume they still don't produce the expected result. But as you didn't explain what you expect the query to return, it's hard to tell the correct statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have the comparison operator within the case statement. Instead, your where clause should be something like:

```
WHERE 
    rownum <= CASE WHEN BLOK = 'DD11' THEN 1
                   ELSE 2
              END
```

Comment: Sorry Boneist for editing your post, I didn't notice your format style @

Comment: @PhamX.Bach you also changed the OP's query (`DD11` was in lowercase after your edits), so I have rolled that back. Please be very careful to not change the OP's meaning when you edit.

Comment: arr, thks you, my mistake today

Answer (score 4):

Why use a case expression?

```
WHERE (
        (BLOK = 'DD11' AND ROWNUM <= 1)
        OR 
        ROWNUM <= 2
    )
```

In general it is advised to use "boolean logic" in where clauses, here is an blog of the topic: [SQL WHERE clauses: Avoid CASE, use Boolean logic](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2003/11/14/513/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to replace where clause to

```
((BLOK = 'DD11' and ROWNUM <= 1) or (ROWNUM <= 2))
```